# Using a subscribe form across Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Right now I have an email subscribe form in my Rails app.

I use Ajax to put it in the navbar, and I have to instantiate @subscriber = Subscriber.new in every controller action I want to use the form in.

Because the form is in the navbar, that effectively means I need to modify every controller action with a view. This works, but kind of sucks.

Is there a better way to do this in Rails? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about putting Subscriber.new directly in your view?

Something like

```
 <%= form_for Subscriber.new do |form| %>
   ...
 <% end %>
```

or... setting the @subscriber in your `application_controller.rb`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_subscriber

  def set_subscriber
    @subscriber = Subscriber.new
  end
end
```

Comment: Somewhat embarrassed I didn't think of that. Thanks!